# Google map is returning wrong location by geocoder in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using google map and I want to search location in it but it is returning me wrong location. I couldn't find what is the problem with it and I need suggestions. Please anybody tell me what should I do?

```
EditText sLocation = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                location = sLocation.getText().toString();

                List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;

                if (location != null || location.length()>0) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    String locality = address.getLocality();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLatitude());
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker"));
                    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

                }
```

Comment: OK,  but it is related to Google map. How can I get correct location in it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting wrong location in google map because I was not getting correct latitude and longitude. Now I am getting correct location by `geocoder` through below code.

```
sButton =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.generalId);
sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            hideSoftKeyboard(v);
            EditText sLocation = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            location = sLocation.getText().toString();

            List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;

            if (location != null || location.length()>0) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
                String locality = address.getLocality();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                double latitude = address.getLatitude();
                double longitude = address.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            }

        }
    });
```

instead of

```
EditText sLocation = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
location = sLocation.getText().toString();

                List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;

                if (location != null || location.length()>0) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    String locality = address.getLocality();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLatitude());
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker"));
                    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

                }
```